# replacing windows

Tags: windows

My husband found a great deal on windows, the challenge is they are brick faced windows. What can we do about installing them on a vinyl home? Is it possible to just add decorative tile around the window to make up the space difference?

Comment: `make up the space difference` between what and what?

Comment: Do you mean the windows have brick mold around them? It is  a common term for the outside molding. If it is made of wood, pull it off and add wider to finish the size you need, if they are vinyl there is plastic trim that will also fill the space

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have found moulding that will fit perfectly with very low maintenance.